# Deleting first 3 rows in Excel with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to delete the first 3 rows from a specific sheet in Excel with Python (openpyxl).

```
excel_file = xl.load_workbook('Test.xlsm')
excel_sheet = excel_file('Data')
excel_sheet.delete_rows(idx=0, amount=3)
excel_file.save('Test.xlsm')
```

But this is not working as expected.

I am getting a long error which ends with:

```
"for idx, c in enumerate(coordinate):
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"
```

What does this mean?

Why are the first 3 rows are not deleted?

Comment: It means `coordinate` is `None`, and you have provided no evidence why you expect that not to be the case.

Comment: What is coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the sheet name using square brackets and the first row is row 1 not row 0

```
excel_sheet = excel_file['Data']
excel_sheet.delete_rows(idx=1, amount=3)
```

Comment: This worked. Sorry, for my late reply. I was sick the past days.